# Do-this-next Indicator as Accessory View in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I want to add a small indicator (like a green arrow or small circle) to indicate to the user what to do next in my iPad app (apparently some of the users can't figure what to do first, even tho' I have instructions in a drop-down help file).  The indicator would be visible **on the left side of the row** and only on the row which would be the next action to take (user should tap that row to get the next sub-view to appear).

Any ideas how to accomplish this?  (I looked on SO and Google and didn't find anything that was pertinent).

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UITableViewCell`? A standard cell has a property for letting you add an icon on the left side of the cell.

Comment: Hi Rick... I saw that, but wasn't if I could make them visible or not... I'll keep reading... thanks again... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an image view to your prototype table cell. When you want to indicate that a given row is the next thing to do, set the image of the image view for that row to your indicator image.